# mounting sftp with ssh-keygen: Remote execution disabled; possible workarounds, other methods

Tags: sftp, ssh-keygen

I try to configure my system so that I can mount an sftp server without my password. I tried to do this with ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id, but got an error.

```
$ ssh-keygen
...
$ ssh-copy-id user@sftp.server
...
361596: Remote execution access has been disabled by the system administrator
exec request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is any workaround for this error or another method that can work, or that I am just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work:

- connect with password and download `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if it exists. (Otherwise, `touch authorized_keys` locally to use en empty file.)
- append your `~/.ssh/*.pub` to the downloaded (or created) file
- re-upload the file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

(Note it's possible that the remote admin has removed the possibility to have public keys there, though.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I now know how this works. Unfortunately, for this specific case it did not work. Could it be because the remote is actually running Windows?